# Why can't I change the keyboard layout? Only one step

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout

I have two languages. If I press <kbd>Alt + Shift</kbd> the language changes to Arabic.
If I press it again, not due to English.

Comment: Are you using Unity or Gnome?  How did you add the language initially?

Comment: Unity, from installation

Comment: Can you type in English?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to manually change it via Preferences?

Can you give it a try? - http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu
Can you try to set a different Keyboard Shortcut?

Comment: when i clicking on the first time  the language changes
and when I click the second time does not change  EN > AR AR~EN